# Contract-First XML attributes (dis)order

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd

I'm having a strange case. I'm using the [contract-first approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674270(v=vs.110).aspx) to develop a WCF Web Service. The thing is I have defined a specific attribute order in the XSD file, with the  tag. Nevertheless the Generated code with the contract-first tool is messing this order, and when I try to send a xml with the specified attribute distribution I'm getting this error (using the SoapUI application):

Element' 'codigoProvinciaField' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InventarioWS.ContractTypes' is not expected. Expecting element 'codigoCorporacionField'
(translated from the message below)

It works when I swap the "codigoCorporacionField" with the "codigoProvinciaField". The thing is I've them defined the other way around in the xml schema.

It seems that without the contract-first approach I can use the [[DataMember(Order = 0)] tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The message:

> 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InventarioWS.ContractTypes'.
>   Se espera el elemento 'codigoCorporacionField'.
>    Error en la línea 9, posición 42. No se esperaban los
>   elementos 'Element' 'codigoProvinciaField' del espacio de nombres
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InventarioWS.ContractTypes'.
>   Se espera el elemento 'codigoCorporacionField'.
>                     en System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex,
>   XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.GetMemberIndexWithRequiredMembers(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames, XmlDictionaryString[]
>   memberNamespaces, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex,
>   ExtensionDataObject extensionData)    en
>   ReadCodigoEnteFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] ,
>   XmlDictionaryString[] )    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&
>   dataContract)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String
>   name, String ns)    en ReadEnvioFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] ,
>   XmlDictionaryString[] )    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&
>   dataContract)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name,
>   String ns)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
>                     System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>                  
>                  El formateador inició una excepción al intentar deserializar el mensaje: Error al intentar deserializar el
>   parámetro http://tempuri.org/:envio. El mensaje de InnerException era
>   'Error en la línea 9, posición 42. No se esperaban los elementos
>   'Element' 'codigoProvinciaField' del espacio de nombres
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InventarioWS.ContractTypes'.
>   Se espera el elemento 'codigoCorporacionField'.'. Consulte
>   InnerException para obtener más información.

The XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="Envio">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element ref="CodigoEnte" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element> 

  <xsd:element name="CodigoEnte">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CodigoComunidad">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="2"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="CodigoProvincia">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="2"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="CodigoCorporacion">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="3"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Tiporg1">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="1"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Tiporg2">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="1"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Tiporg3">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:length value="3"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And the XML sent using SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:inv="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InventarioWS.ContractTypes">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:RecuperaCorporacionXCodigo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:envio>
            <inv:codigoEnteField>
               <inv:codigoComunidadField>12</inv:codigoComunidadField>
               <inv:codigoProvinciaField>28</inv:codigoProvinciaField>
               <inv:codigoCorporacionField>022</inv:codigoCorporacionField>
               <inv:tiporg1Field>A</inv:tiporg1Field>
               <inv:tiporg2Field>A</inv:tiporg2Field>
               <inv:tiporg3Field>000</inv:tiporg3Field>
            </inv:codigoEnteField>
            <inv:versionField>?</inv:versionField>
         </tem:envio>
      </tem:RecuperaCorporacionXCodigo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Edit:  I forgot to say the error comes from an unsolicicited alfabetical order given by the framework/tool. In this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/12ab002d-f49f-4e25-9adb-ddbb58174efe/error-while-trying-to-deserialize-parameter?forum=silverlightnet) says:

> By specifying the Order property in this way, RegionID will come before RegionDescription in the generated schema. Without this property, the sequence in the schema is sorted alphabetically. Visual Studio will generate the correct proxy, but I don't know how your own class looks like. Make sure your client side specify the same Order property.

Comment: Why do you put versionField after codigoEnteField in the XML file? The XSD schematic says it should precede codigoEnteField.

Comment: You're right, I changed that order, but it doesn't affect to my previous error.

Comment: A little off topic, but you shouldn't use numbers in element names.  It's legal XML, but terrible for people consuming it. Most XML developers would expect to be able to get all your tiporg fields with //inv:tiporg not //inv:tiporg1, //inv:tiporg2, //inv:tiporg3, etc.

Comment: I think you aren't going to like the workaround I'd to come with, then :P. Just out of curiosity, why is it recommended not to use numbers? Does it difficult the xml mapping or something related?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why the problems manifests itself, but I do think there is a workaround.
Replace `<xsd:sequence>` in your XSD with `<xs:all>`. The `<all>` indicator specifies that the child elements can appear in any order, and that each child element must occur only once. This should fix your problem.

Comment: I've tried, and the problem persists. Also, the xs:all would fix the error, but also keep the attributes disorder, and it's a customer requirement. It was a nice try, though.

Comment: Diego is right.  Order doesn't matter in XML, only the document hierarchy (what includes what) matters.

Comment: I disagree. If it doesn't matter, why am I getting this error? The internal xml mapping is complaining about System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException. Also, if you use the xs:sequence it expects the same order you've defined, not so the xs:all tag. That's why I think Diego's answer has a point.

Comment: Sometimes order matters. Take for example XHTML: the order of e.g. paragraphs in the document should be respected, for obvious reasons. But in many other instances order doesn't or rather shouldn't matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround, by renaming the troublesome attributes with a "param1..." prefix. I write this for future references, but should have a REAL fix.